# 123 to 321 problem giving errors when iterating

Tags: python

I made this program trying to solve a problem which is fliping a number. For example, when the number 123 is the number inputed the number 321 should be the output.

```
#function to swap number positions on the array

def swapPositions(list, pos1, pos2):
    i = list[pos1]
    list[pos1] = list[pos2]
    list[pos2] = i


myList = []


theNum = int(input("enter the value"))
theNumInString = str(theNum)


#loop to separate numbers on the integer into each position of the array

for char in theNum2:
    myList.append(char)


#this variable is to know how many times we should swap the positions
numofSwaps = len(myList) % 2

posi1 = 0
posi2 = len(myList) - 1
while numofSwaps != 0:
    swapPositions(myList, posi1, posi2)
    
    #I add one and subtract one from the positions so they move further to the middle to swap other positions
    posi1 += 1                   
    posi2 -= 1
    numofSwaps -= 1

number = "".join(myList)
print(number)
```

what happens when I run the code and try for example 123 it returns 321 as expected
BUT here comes the problem... when I input 12345 the output is 52341 which only swaps the outer two numbers.

Comment: The [divide operator](https://www.educative.io/answers/what-are-division-operators-in-python) is `/`, not `%`. But you actually want `//`, which rounds down.

Comment: The easy way to flip a number is `int(str(theNum)[::-1])`.

Comment: Note that python allows assignment of multiple values, so your swap function could be better written as `list[pos1],list[pos2] = list[pos2],list[pos1]`. Also, turning your string into a list is simply done by `myList = list(theNum2)`

Comment: Don't use _list_ as variable name, there's already a built-in class with that name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this can be done without converting the number to a string, for example

```
# note: this example works for positive numbers only
def reverseNum(x):
    y = 0
    while x > 0:
        y = y*10 + x%10
        x //= 10
    return y
```

```
>>> reverseNum(3124)
4213
```